# How to handle clicks with recyclerview that has headers

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that show images. I added a header to this recyclerview so it groups pictures under each year. To do this I had to implement a List. I build that list by adding a year string for header then all the images for that year. here is what that looks like

```
for (int x = 0; x < sortListYear.size(); x++) {
            mCombinedList.add(sortListYear.get(x));
            for (int i = 0; i < media.size(); i++) {
                if (sdfFrom.format(media.get(i).getDateModified()).equalsIgnoreCase(sortListYear.get(x))){
                    mCombinedList.add(media.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Then my other adapter functions

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mCombinedList.get(position) instanceof String){
            return TypeItem.TYPE_HEAD;
        } else {
            return TypeItem.TYPE_MEDIA;
        }
    }

@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TypeItem.TYPE_HEAD) {
            return new HeadHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_text, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new MediaHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_photo, parent, false));
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ThemedViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof HeadHolder) {
            String string = (String) mCombinedList.get(position);
            ((HeadHolder)holder).bindView(string, position);
        } else {
            Media m = (Media) mCombinedList.get(position);
            ((MediaHolder)holder).bindView(m, position);
        }
    }
```

Before I added the header this is how I would get my images arraylist

```
public ArrayList<Media> getMedia() {
        return media;
    }
```

The problem is i replaced that with my mCombinedList that contains the headers. How can I get just my media without headers? Also won't position in the adapter be an issue?

I also have methods getSelected() and getFirstSelected().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to tackle this. If you're just interested in listening to item clicks, one method would be to define a listener for the clicks.

```
interface MediaClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Media item);
}
```

Then inside your adapter you can hold a reference to a listener to forward events onto.

```
private MediaClickListener clickListener;

void setClickListener(MediaClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}
```

Next, ensure your `MediaHolder` is a non-static inner class of your adapter. When you call `bindView()` on your `MediaHolder`, you should store a reference to the `Media` item that it's currently bound to.

```
private Media currentItem;

void bindView(Media media) {
    currentItem = media;
}
```

Finally, when your `MediaHolder` is instantiated, add your view `OnClickListener`.

```
MediaHolder(View view) {
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
             if (clickListener != null) clickListener.onItemClick(currentItem);
        } 
    });
}
```

Because your holder is a non-static inner class, it has access to the surrounding adapter's `clickLister`.

---

If you want to keep track of items that have been selected, then you could hold a `List<Media>` in your adapter.

```
private List<Media> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then in `MediaHolder` you could add/remove items from that collection as the user interacts with them.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        if (selectedItems.contains(currentItem)) selectedItems.remove(currentItem);
        else selectedItems.add(currentItem);
    }
});
```

This would allow you to retrieve all selected items in your `getSelected()` method.

Comment: That seems like it might work. What about handling the getselected media when more than one are selected?

Comment: Updated my answer to include collecting selected items.

Comment: great. what about the position? When i click one item it opens a viewer activity and needs that List of media items but also need the position of that selected media file to set viewpager. I can't user adapter position because it has the headers.

Comment: Could you explain why you need the position?